# Difference between Round and Int function in PYTHON

Tags: python

Hi Can you please refer to below sample code and let me know what is the exact difference between round and int functions
OUTPUT:
12 dollars and 0 cents
12 dollars and 1.0 cents

```
# code is to convert xx.yy to xx dollars and yy cents **
val = 12.01                  
dollars = int(val)  #Integer value to know how many Dollars
cents = int(100 * (val - dollars))   #Integer value to know how many cents
print str(dollars) + " dollars and " + str(cents) + " cents"
```

If i write the same code with round function, I am getting right answer

```
val = 12.01                  
dollars = int(val)  #Integer value to know how many Dollars
cents = round(100 * (val - dollars))   #Integer value to know how many cents
print str(dollars) + " dollars and " + str(cents) + " cents"
```

Not sure why it is shown as 0 cents when i use int.

Comment: This is the first time i am using stackoverflow. Please ignore formatting mistakes. Below is the code using ROUND function:

Answer (score 2):

You are using float values, they do not map cleanly to decimal values.

If you try something like:

```
floatcents = 100 * (val - dollars)
cents = int(floatcents)

 print floatcents
 print cents
```

You may well end up with `floatcents` being something like `0.999999999789` and that, truncated to an integer value, becomes 0 instead of 1.

You may be better off using `int((100*val) - (100*dollars))` or simply use an integral value of cents instead of having a float value of dollars.

Answer (score 0):

int() gets rid of any decimal points. You should instead use:

```
cents = float(100 * (val - dollars))   #Integer value to know how many cents
```

explanation:

The following code treats everything as an integer, so (val - dollars) will give you 0 instead of 0.1 therefore multiplying by 100 will still give you 0.

```
int(100 * (val - dollars))
```

Answer (score 0):

an integer is a whole number
and a float is a number with decimal points 
that's the layman's terms of it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming val is the result of some calculation and might be for example

```
  val=12.996
```

You should actually round the dollar result as well:

```
  dollar = round(val*100)/100
  cents = round(val*100)-dollar*100

  -> $13 + 0 cents , not $12 + 100 cents...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accurately represent currency, consider using the [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) type:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 2
val = Decimal(12.01)
dollars = int(val)
cents = int(100 * (val - dollars))
print(str(dollars) + " dollars and " + str(cents) + " cents")
```

Returns:

```
12 dollars and 1 cents
```